# How to correctly use Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my jhipster gateway application I have a repository (extends R2dbcRepository) a method which should return me every value connected to an id. But I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot apply reactive transaction to non-reactive return type: interface java.util.List
```

I tried adding the transactional annotation but it did not help. Could someone take a look and tell me what my mistake is.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ReceiptService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReceiptService.class);

    private final ReceiptRepository receiptRepository;

    private final RceiptRepository rceiptRepository;
    private final ReceiptMapper receiptMapper;


    public ReceiptService(ReceiptRepository receiptRepository, RceiptRepository rceiptRepository, ReceiptMapper receiptMapper) {
        this.receiptRepository = receiptRepository;
        this.rceiptRepository = rceiptRepository;
        //   this.rceiptRepository = rceiptRepository;
        this.receiptMapper = receiptMapper;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<ReceiptDTO> findByCompany(Long companyUserID) {
        log.debug("Request to get all Receipts by a company");
        return receiptRepository.findReceiptsByCompanyId(companyUserID).stream().map(receiptMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ReceiptRepository extends R2dbcRepository<Receipt, Long>, ReceiptRepositoryInternal {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM receipt entity WHERE entity.user_receipt_id = :id")
    Flux<Receipt> findByUser_receipt(Long id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM receipt entity WHERE entity.user_receipt_id IS NULL")
    Flux<Receipt> findAllWhereUser_receiptIsNull();

    // just to avoid having unambigous methods
    @Override
    Flux<Receipt> findAll();

    @Override
    List<Receipt> findReceiptsByCompanyId(Long id);

    @Override
    Mono<Receipt> findById(Long id);


    @Override
    <S extends Receipt> Mono<S> save(S entity);
}

interface ReceiptRepositoryInternal{
    <S extends Receipt> Mono<S> insert(S entity);
    <S extends Receipt> Mono<S> save(S entity);
    Mono<Integer> update(Receipt entity);

    Flux<Receipt> findAll();
    Mono<Receipt> findById(Long id);
    Flux<Receipt> findAllBy(Pageable pageable);
    Flux<Receipt> findAllBy(Pageable pageable, Criteria criteria);

    List<Receipt> findReceiptsByCompanyId(Long id);


}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ReceiptResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReceiptResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "receipt";

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    private final ReceiptService receiptService;

    private final ReceiptRepository receiptRepository;

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public ReceiptResource(ReceiptService receiptService, ReceiptRepository receiptRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.receiptService = receiptService;
        this.receiptRepository = receiptRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@code POST  /receipts} : Create a new receipt.
     *
     * @param receiptDTO the receiptDTO to create.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 201 (Created)} and with body the new receiptDTO, or with status {@code 400 (Bad Request)} if the receipt has already an ID.
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect.
     */

    @PostMapping("/receipts")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<ReceiptDTO>> createReceipt(@RequestBody ReceiptDTO receiptDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Receipt : {}", receiptDTO);
        if (receiptDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new receipt cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        return receiptService
            .save(receiptDTO)
            .map(result -> {
                try {
                    return ResponseEntity
                        .created(new URI("/api/receipts/" + result.getId()))
                        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
                        .body(result);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
    }

    @GetMapping("/receipts/byUserId")
    public List<ReceiptDTO> getAllReceiptsByCompanyId(@RequestParam Long companyId) {
        log.debug("REST request to get all Receipts");

        return receiptService.findByCompany(companyId);
    }

}
```

Complete Service class:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ReceiptService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReceiptService.class);

    private final ReceiptRepository receiptRepository;

    private final ReceiptMapper receiptMapper;


    public ReceiptService(ReceiptRepository receiptRepository, ReceiptMapper receiptMapper) {
        this.receiptRepository = receiptRepository;
        this.receiptMapper = receiptMapper;
    }

    /**
     * Save a receipt.
     *
     * @param receiptDTO the entity to save.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public Mono<ReceiptDTO> save(ReceiptDTO receiptDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Receipt : {}", receiptDTO);
        return receiptRepository.save(receiptMapper.toEntity(receiptDTO)).map(receiptMapper::toDto);
    }

    /**
     * Partially update a receipt.
     *
     * @param receiptDTO the entity to update partially.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public Mono<ReceiptDTO> partialUpdate(ReceiptDTO receiptDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to partially update Receipt : {}", receiptDTO);

        return receiptRepository
            .findById(receiptDTO.getId())
            .map(existingReceipt -> {
                receiptMapper.partialUpdate(existingReceipt, receiptDTO);

                return existingReceipt;
            })
            .flatMap(receiptRepository::save)
            .map(receiptMapper::toDto);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<ReceiptDTO> findByCompany(Long companyUserID) {
        log.debug("Request to get all Receipts by a company");
        return receiptRepository.findReceiptsByCompanyId(companyUserID).stream().map(receiptMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

//    public List<ReceiptDTO> findByCompanyJpa(Long companyUserID) {
//        log.debug("Request to get all Receipts by a company");
//        return rceiptRepository.findReceiptsByCompanyId(companyUserID).stream().map(receiptMapper::toDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
//    }

    /**
     * Get all the receipts.
     *
     * @return the list of entities.
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Flux<ReceiptDTO> findAll() {
        log.debug("Request to get all Receipts");
        return receiptRepository.findAll().map(receiptMapper::toDto);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of receipts available.
     *
     * @return the number of entities in the database.
     */
    public Mono<Long> countAll() {
        return receiptRepository.count();
    }

    /**
     * Get one receipt by id.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     * @return the entity.
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Mono<ReceiptDTO> findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Receipt : {}", id);
        return receiptRepository.findById(id).map(receiptMapper::toDto);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the receipt by id.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     * @return a Mono to signal the deletion
     */
    public Mono<Void> delete(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to delete Receipt : {}", id);
        return receiptRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot apply reactive transaction to non-reactive return type: interface java.util.List
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.lambda$invokeWithinTransaction$0(TransactionAspectSupport.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:353)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:692)
    at com.nosi.gateway.service.ReceiptService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a802f8a9.findByCompany(<generated>)
    at com.nosi.gateway.web.rest.ReceiptResource.getAllReceiptsByCompanyId(ReceiptResource.java:85)
    at com.nosi.gateway.web.rest.ReceiptResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a680ab7a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:779)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at com.nosi.gateway.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:103)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

Comment: Try removing the `@Transactional` annotation from `ReceiptService`. Are there more methods in that class that you haven't shown in your post? Perhaps one that called a reactive repository method, annotated with `@Transactional`, and returns a `List`? Can you please show the entire stack trace?

Comment: There are more I will update the question with complete service

Comment: I deleted transactional from service but still the same error. Now I will give you the complete stacktrace

Comment: I can not post the stacktrace because it is too long getting the error that I have exceeded the body limit. I will post a bit more nevertheless

Comment: I added the stacktrace

Comment: Can we please see the rest of your service?

Comment: it is above the error this is my complete ReceiptService

Comment: It's probably because your service method uses a reactive interface `R2dbcRepository` method but does not return a reactive type. Just because your repository method `findReceiptsByCompanyId` doesn't return `Mono` or `Flux`, doesn't mean that the generated Spring code doesn't use reactive code.

Comment: I tried to return a Flux but then I am getting the following error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No MethodInvocation found: Check that an AOP invocation is in progress and that the ExposeInvocationInterceptor is upfront in the interceptor chain. Specifically, note that advices with order HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE will execute before ExposeInvocationInterceptor! In addition, ExposeInvocationInterceptor and ExposeInvocationInterceptor.currentInvocation() must be invoked from the same thread.

Comment: Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: Sorry, I do not. I have little experience with Spring Reactive.